# Dynamically create subcription callback functions (Python)

Tags: ros, ros2, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to generalize one of my nodes to subscribe to not just a different set of topics, but a different number of topics, depending on the situation. Specifically I want it to republish the data it receives on a given topic, to a topic with a similar name and the incoming data modified in some way.

Given a dictionary of topic names, I figured I could do this in a loop like so:

```
class DynamicSubscriptions(Node):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__("dynamic_subscriptions")

    list_of_subs_to_make = [  # Could come from a parameter, be added as the node runs, ... 
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
    ]

    self.subscribers = {}
    self.sub_callbacks = {}
    self.pubs = {}

    for topic in list_of_subs_to_make:

        self.pubs[topic] = self.create_publisher(
            Float64,
            topic + '/republished',
            QoSPresetProfiles.SENSOR_DATA.value
        )

        new_cb = self.make_callback(topic)
        self.sub_callbacks[topic] = new_cb

        self.subscribers[topic] = self.create_subscription(
            Float64,  # Leaving these the same for all topics, for simplicity of the example
            topic, 
            new_cb,
            QoSPresetProfiles.SENSOR_DATA.value
        )
    
    for topic, sub in self.subscribers.items():
        self.get_logger().info(f"topic {topic} subscription {sub}")

def make_callback(self, topic_name):
    def callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info("Inside {topic_name} callback, got {msg}")
    return callback
```

If I run the node, and try publishing to the topics, I get this error:

```
root@thomas-Precision-5530-big:/workdir# ros2 run rloc_subsystems dynamic_subscriptions 
[INFO] [1650860469.579535172] [dynamic_subscriptions]: topic one subscription <rclpy.subscription.Subscription object at 0x7fb30ce415b0>
[INFO] [1650860469.580131489] [dynamic_subscriptions]: topic two subscription <rclpy.subscription.Subscription object at 0x7fb30ce41760>
[INFO] [1650860469.580512294] [dynamic_subscriptions]: topic three subscription <rclpy.subscription.Subscription object at 0x7fb30ce41910>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workdir/install/rloc_subsystems/lib/rloc_subsystems/dynamic_subscriptions", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "/workdir/install/rloc_subsystems/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rloc_subsystems/wheel_odometry/dynamic_minimal.py", line 65, in main
    rclpy.spin(node)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 191, in spin
    executor.spin_once()
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 711, in spin_once
    raise handler.exception()
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/task.py", line 239, in __call__
    self._handler.send(None)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 426, in handler
    await call_coroutine(entity, arg)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 351, in _execute_subscription
    await await_or_execute(sub.callback, msg)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 118, in await_or_execute
    return callback(*args)
TypeError: callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
root@thomas-Precision-5530-big:/workdir#
```

What am I missing? Is there a better way to achieve my goal? I understand this may be a problem with how I am using python, and not a ROS problem.

I am using ROS2 Foxy on Docker using `osrf/ros:foxy-desktop` image ([described here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Run-2-nodes-in-single-or-separate-docker-containers.html)), Python 3.8.5

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399540/dynamically-create-subcription-callback-functions-(python)/) by [somebody un](https://answers.ros.org/users/39714/somebody-un/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's happening is that you're assigning `new_cb` a local scope function of `DynamicSubscriptions.make_callback()`. As such, `new_cb` does not represent a bound method of the `DynamicSubscriptions` class, i.e. it isn't a method that is bound to an instance of `DynamicSubscriptions`.

This is a problem because when the executor calls the callback with the arguments (just the published message instance), it populates the `self` parameter (since it isn't bound to an instance) rather than the `msg` parameter.

What you can do is return the bound method `callback()` as such:

```
def make_callback(self, topic_name):
        def callback(self, msg):
            self.get_logger().info("Inside {topic_name} callback, got {msg}")
        setattr(self, 'callback', callback.__get__(self, self.__class__))
        return self.callback
```

If you don't need the callback to be a class method, you could also just remove the `self` parameter and get a free-standing callable. Maybe something like:

```
def make_callback(self, topic_name):
    def callback(msg):
        print(f'In callback, got {msg}') # can't use rclpy.Node methods now
    return callback
```

---

Originally posted by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) with karma: 456 on 2022-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [somebody un](https://answers.ros.org/users/39714/somebody-un/) on 2022-04-25**:
Thank you for your answer. I will need the callback to be a class method, since I want to publish something using the msg. So I don't think a free-standing callable will work for me.

Your idea of returning the bound method sounds like it should work. However as you have written it, `self.callback` does not exist, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'DynamicSubscriptions' object has no attribute 'callback' # <- from the `return self.callback` line
```

If I add it to the class like so:

```
def make_callback(self, topic_name):
    def callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info("Inside {topic_name} callback, got {msg}")
    self.cb = callback
    return self.cb
```

I get the same TypeError as before:

```
TypeError: callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
```

**Comment by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) on 2022-04-25**:
Ah, my bad. I forgot to actually bind the unbound `callback` method to the class. This updated snippet should work:

```
def make_callback(self, topic_name):
    def callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info(f'Inside {topic_name} callback, got {msg}')
    setattr(self, 'callback', callback.__get__(self, self.__class__)) # bind
    return self.callback
```

For implementation reference: https://gist.github.com/hangtwenty/a928b801ca5c7705e94e

I've updated my original answer to that effect. Thanks for pointing out the problem!

**Comment by [somebody un](https://answers.ros.org/users/39714/somebody-un/) on 2022-04-25**:
This works, amazing! Thank you! Today I learned about binding :)